# Selecting data based on a partial composite key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core (code-first), I'm trying to select data from an existing table based on a composite key. I'm unable to change the database definitions.

One table has a composite key, the other table only has one of the columns in the composite key. I think I can demonstrate this using the [Microsoft Foreign Key Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships#Foreign%20Key), the only change would be that `CarState` doesn't exist on `RecordOfSale` (or becomes `NotMapped`).

Question is, using Entity Framework Core 2.2, how do I select based on a partial key rather than the full composite key (if that's even possible?). I have tried using constant values, virtual columns, computed properties. Existing database code using SQL defines a constant value in the predicate for the missing column (but it depends which SQL queries are run as to which constant value is chosen, this value isn't held in a table/field) eg,

```
WHERE CarState = 'OHIO'
```

Hope that makes sense, the Microsoft example is below:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.State, c.LicensePlate });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RecordOfSale>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Car)
            .WithMany(c => c.SaleHistory)
            .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.CarState, s.CarLicensePlate });
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public List<RecordOfSale> SaleHistory { get; set; }
}

public class RecordOfSale
{
    public int RecordOfSaleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string CarState { get; set; }
    public string CarLicensePlate { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a speculative query (e.g. in LINQ) that shows what you’re trying to do, and tell us how it fails?

Comment: .Where(x => x.Key.ABC == "XYZ")

Comment: have you tried this?: var query = ctx.Cars.Where(item => item.State == "OHIO");

Comment: You can query such raw table structure, but you can't represent that in the entity model with one-to-many relationship as you are trying, because what you are explaining is technically many-to-many relationship, thus requires intermediate link table/entity.